# How to read a value from .cnf file?

Tags: bash

What's an efficient bash command to read a value from a .cnf file? I specifically want to return the first password value from /etc/mysql/debian.cnf, which looks like this:

```
[client]
host     = localhost
user     = debian-sys-maint
password = foo
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysql_upgrade]
host     = localhost
user     = debian-sys-maint
password = foo
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
basedir  = /usr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can for example do:

```
$ awk '/^password/ {print $3; exit}' file
foo
```

It looks for lines starting with exactly "password" (to avoid commented lines, that would start with `#`) and, once found, prints the third field on them. Then, it exits; this way, you will just have one output (or none, if no lines match this pattern).

To store it in a variable:

```
$ mypass=$(awk '/^password/ {print $3; exit}' file)
$ echo "$mypass"
foo
```

---

You can also use this:

```
awk '/^password/ {split($0, a, "="); gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/, "", a[2]); print a[2]; exit}' file
```

It matches the line starting with `password`, slices it based on `=` field and prints the second field. This way, `password=hello` would also work, that is, trailing spaces won't interfere the final solution.

Comment: As for the third solution, you could also do something along the lines of `awk -F'=' '$1 ~ "^password" { print $2 ; exit }' file | tr -d "\"'\t "`. That way it might be a bit easier to see what's going on, and as far as I know, you are not reliant on having `gawk` (But now you need `tr`). I can't speak to the robustness vs. your proposed solution, hence why I'm not going to edit.

Comment: It sounds good, @SteenSchütt It is more readable than that gsub-fu I was doing here. Feel free to edit it in as an alternative, if you want!

Answer (score 1):

using sed:

```
sed -n '/^password /{s/.*= *//p;q}' /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
```