# My .sh consider config values as command

Tags: bash, shell

I try to use the values of my config file into my .sh file but it seems it's considered as command.

Here is my **test_config.sh**:

```
source pathTo/config.cnf
echo "Name=$user"
echo "Surname=$host"
```

**config.cnf**

```
[client]
user = root
password = pwd
host = localhost
```

The error appeared is:

```
 $ ./test_config.sh
```

> config.cnf: line 1: user: command not found
>      config.cnf: line 2: password: command not found
>      config.cnf: line 3: host: command not found

Comment: What tool are you expecting to read your config file? You need to run that tool, not source.

Comment: I didn't understand your question Gem. Can you please give me more explication ?

Comment: As @Matteo says, bash does not understand .inf files. Specific applications understand specific .inf files. You didn't really say why you wanted to run this .inf file, so I suggested you run the application. I don't think that is what you wanted.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290018/how-to-read-a-value-from-cnf-file?s=1|101.9239

Comment: if you want to `.` source the file, you'd have to get rid of those `[section]` headers and replace `<space>=<space>` with `=`

Comment: Thanks Gem for your reply, so what I want to do is to use parameters (user, password, host) into my sh file to avoid writing the same values in many sh files in the future I prefer to have one config file that  contains my parameters and use them wherever I want.

Comment: @MartinZeitler there is spaces between arguments and values. I also try to replace source by . / but it doesn't work too.

Comment: @zackzulg the below answer merely does what I've suggested... here is a better matching dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318809/how-do-i-grab-an-ini-value-within-a-shell-script ...including parsing the sections, hence what you suffixed `.cfg` there equals the classical `.ini` format.

Comment: one can use just any scripting-language available to the command prompt, translating the input (as shown above) into the output (as shown below), in order to initialize the variables, by sourcing a shell-script - or other script. adding arguments to the shell-script and then using `$1`, `$2`, `$3` might be worth a consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`source`is a bash shell built-in command that executes the content of the file passed as argument, in the current shell. It has a synonym in `.` (period).

This means that `pathTo/config.cnf` is executed as a bash script.

You could rewrite your configuration file as a shell script

```
# client
user=root
password=pwd
host=localhost
```

and then source it

Comment: Thanks Matteo for your explications, but the config file is used in many places in project so is there a way to use parameters into my sh file ?

Comment: `bash` does not understand this format and you cannot use it directly. You will have either to convert it or to write some routines to parse it.

Comment: Ok thank you @Matteo